# Elastic Search - Sort by multiple fields with the missing parameter

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, filter

I am trying to apply a sort to an Elastic Search query by two different fields:

`price_sold` and `price_list`

I would like to first sort on `price_sold`, but if that value is null, I would like to then sort by `price_list`

Would the query be correct if I just set the sorts to:

```
"sort": [
 { "price_sold": { "order": "desc"}},
 { "price_list": { "order": "desc"}}
]
```

I have executed the query, and I do not get any errors, and it seems like the results are correct, however I am curious if I have overlooked something.

I have been reading about the `missing` filter, along with possibly using a `custom value`.  This may not be required, but I am not quite sure.

Would there be a way to define a second field to sort on if the first field is missing, or is that not necessary? Something like:

`"sort": [{"price_sold: {"order": "desc", "missing": "doc['field_name']"}]`

Would simply adding these two sorts give me the desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't try the queries you are asking about...

Comment: What is the error you get when executing the query ?

Comment: I have tried the queries, the first set of sorts doesn't give an error, I am just curious if there is a better way to do it or if I am overlooking something.  The second query does not work, but thats expected as I have not been able to find any documentation to support that format - its more of a pseudo code attempt to get the point across.

Comment: There is a `missing` option for `sort`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_missing_values

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yeah, I saw the `missing` option, however I don't think that setting it to _first or _last is what I want.  I was curious about the `custom value` but didn't see any other documentation about how to use that in this context.

Comment: It's hard to give a suggestion to a post that's ambiguous. You haven't mentioned details and only after asking questions you start saying bits and pieces. I'd like to see an example from your tests where you show something that's not working as expected and to explain what's that thing that doesn't work. So far, I'm not clear what you want and what doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I'm just trying to determine if what I am doing is the correct approach, as I am fairly new to elastic search queries, or if there is a better way to do it. I feel the explanation of my question is pretty clear, I have described what I am trying to accomplish, along with a sample solution. Sorry if I am not explaining it well, I am not sure how else to describe it.

Comment: Does your query work as expected? If yes, then you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you're asking.  In SQL terms, you'd like to **ORDER BY COALESCE(price_sold, price_list) DESC**.

The first sort you listed is a little different.  It's similar to **ORDER BY price_sold DESC, price_list DESC** - in other words, primary sort is by price_sold, and for entries where price_sold is equal, secondary sort is by price_list.

Your second sort attempt would be great if "missing" worked that way.  Unfortunately, missing's "custom" option appears to allow you to specify a constant value only.

If you don't need to limit your search using from and size, you should be able to use sort's _script option to write some logic that works for you.  I ended up here because I do use from and size to retrieve batches, and when I sort by _script, the items I'm getting don't make sense - the items are sorted correctly, but I'm not getting the right set of items.  So, I added a new analyzer and expanded my fields to use the new analyzer, and I was hoping to be able to sort using the new field or, if the new field doesn't exist (for previously-indexed items), use the old field's value instead.  But that doesn't seem to be possible.  I think I'm going to have to reindex my items so my new field is populated.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is still looking I ended up creating a script similar to this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty&size=10&from=0' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "inline": "doc[\u0027price_sold\u0027] == null ? doc[\u0027price_list\u0027].value : doc[\u0027price_sold\u0027].value"
            },
            "order" : "desc"
        }
    },
}
'
```

For sorting **dates**, the type still has to remain `number` but you replace `.value` with `.date.getMillisOfDay()` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32941178/1342199).

The `from` and `size` worked fine in my version of ElasticSearch (5.1.1). 
To make sure your algorithm is working fine check the generated value in the response, e.g.: `"sort" : [ 5.0622E7 ]`.

Comment: It seems your nullcheck logic is reversed here; shouldn't it be `"inline": "doc[\u0027price_sold\u0027] != null ? doc[\u0027price_sold\u0027].value : doc[\u0027price_list\u0027].value"`?