# How to sort in Elasticserch by the arithmetic difference of two fields

Tags: java, sorting, elasticsearch

Is it possible to sort Elasticserch data by the arithmetic difference between the two fields?
The data are like this:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "price": 500.0,
    "discount": 10.0,
}
```

And I need to sort the data by the difference `price - discount`.
Is it possible in general?

I am also interested in the implementation of it via Java API.

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32941178/4604579

Comment: @talex that's the same link as mine ;-)

Comment: @Val yes. That was automatic comment. It is added every time someone vote to close question as duplicate. :)

Comment: @Val and @talex thank you for the link. It helps me to understand that I need to use a `script` in the sorting procedure.

Comment: That's correct. Try it out and let us know if you need additional guidance.